# открытие картинки fancybox в два клика

Tags: javascript, изображения, fancybox

Установил `fancybox`. сделал обработчик события:

```
$('a.fancybox-a-img').click(function() {
    $(this).fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title : {
                type : 'float'
            }
        },
        'showCloseButton': true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Проблема в том что при первом открытии картинки нужно нажать два раза. После того как она откроется она открывается с первого раза.

Что это может быть? посмотрел по событиям в хроме - только моё. других нет.

Comment: а почему .fancybox ВНУТРИ клика???? Откуда такой код взяли? .fancybox надо присваивать при загрузке страницы, изучайте примеры внимательнее!

Comment: @СергейВ. Спасибо. помогло.

Comment: перенес в ответ, отметь плииз если ответ правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему .fancybox ВНУТРИ клика???? Откуда такой код взяли? .fancybox надо присваивать при загрузке страницы, изучайте примеры внимательнее!